# Does '&' in bash cause Zombie Processes?

Tags: bash, process, fork, wait, zombie-process

A colleague insists that I need to call `wait()` after using `&` in a Bash script to spawn multiple child processes. I believe that the concern is that because the parent process is exiting before the child processes do, they'll be orphaned and left in zombie states.

I understand that `fork()` requires `wait()` or `waitpid()` to properly delete the file descriptors it creates. However, is this really needed for Bash? Isn't this something the bash subshell each child process is running in takes care of? In my own experimentation, I have not been able to recreate a situation in which a Bash child process I've created is left in a zombie state.

Comment: It isn't true that '`fork()` requires `wait()` or `waitpid()` to properly delete the file descriptors it creates'.  To the extent that `fork()` creates file descriptors (it copies them, really), they are closed when the child process exits, before it becomes a zombie.

Answer (score 2):

Processes whose parents die are reparented to `init`, which should eventually reap them when they exit. What causes zombie processes is when the parent process keeps living, but never gets around to reaping the child for some reason.